# capture a iterator in a returned struct

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Newbie here, still struggling with ownership.

I would like to know how I can, in a function, returns a borrow from a struct wrapped in another struct. Here is an example :

```rust
struct Data {
    data: [String; 10]
}

struct DataIterator<'a> {
    value: &'a std::slice::IterMut<'a, String>
}

impl Data {
    fn get_string(&mut self) -> DataIterator {
        let result = DataIterator {
            value: &self.data.iter_mut()
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is a link [to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e7c5d0ce77ea1feeb83fe6a098742dfd).

The idea would be to get a usable iterator, where the data from the Data struct is borrowed, and can be modified, and then, when the return value of the get_string function is dropped, the borrow stops.

However, I'm getting an error where the data cannot be returned as it is owned by the function.

I've tried my best to simplify the issue, as in my case it gets more complicated and I didn't want to give lots of useless information, but I'm trying to return several iterator from the original struct and borrow the fields of the struct doing so.

Is there a way to "capture" the iterator and borrow it using such a function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_string()` function **creates** the iterator; it as a temporary value, and returning a reference to it is forbidden (it would be dangling).

I don't think you need to store a reference to the iterator.
You could simply store the iterator as a value.

It however refers to the original container.
The `'a` in `IterMut` is implicitly the lifetime of `&mut self` in `get_string()`.
Then, when this `DataIterator` will be dropped, the exclusive borrow of the `Data` will stop.

```rust
struct Data {
    data: [String; 10],
}

struct DataIterator<'a> {
    value: std::slice::IterMut<'a, String>,
}

impl Data {
    fn get_string(&mut self) -> DataIterator {
        DataIterator {
            value: self.data.iter_mut(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut d = Data {
        data: Default::default(),
    };
    //
    // a first exclusive-borrow of d starts here...
    d.get_string().value.enumerate().for_each(|(i, e)| {
        *e = format!("elem {}", i);
    });
    // ... the first exclusive-borrow of d stops here
    //
    // a second exclusive-borrow of d starts here...
    let it = d.get_string();
    // println!("CANNOT borrow data: {:?}", d.data);
    it.value.for_each(|e| {
        println!("{:?}", e);
    });
    // ... it is not used anymore below this line,
    // ... the second exclusive-borrow of d stops here
    //
    println!("can borrow data: {:?}", d.data);
}
/*
"elem 0"
"elem 1"
"elem 2"
"elem 3"
"elem 4"
"elem 5"
"elem 6"
"elem 7"
"elem 8"
"elem 9"
can borrow data: ["elem 0", "elem 1", "elem 2", "elem 3", "elem 4", "elem 5", "elem 6", "elem 7", "elem 8", "elem 9"]
*/
```

Comment: Turns out I was overthinking it, as I wanted to borrow the values, I though I needed a reference to the iterator itself. But this is the way to go !